# Why is my code leaking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments, libxml2

**UPDATE2** I think I found the true source of the leaks. I had some business objects that have string properties I forgot to release. These string properties were copied from my custom xlm node object, created here (KGYXMLNode) I don't understandt why the leak is reported here instead of my custom class. My NSString properties were `copy` and not `retain`.

**UPDATE: I think it was a bug in Instruments or something or it doesn't magically leak anymore, but since xcode 4 it doesn't show this leak.**

Hello, according to instruments i have a leak in the following code. I've built an objective-c wrapper around certain libxml functions to be able to parse xml docs using xpath, and in this method I'm setting the innerText for my custom node object.

```
-(void) SetInnerTextForNode: (xmlNodePtr) node : (KGYXMLNode *) obcNode
{
  if ((node) && (node->children))
  {
    for (xmlNodePtr pnode = node->children; pnode != NULL; pnode = pnode->next)
    {
      if (pnode->type == XML_TEXT_NODE)
      {
        xmlChar *content = pnode->content;
        NSString *innerText = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (char *)content];
        NSString *trimmedText = [innerText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: trimCharSet];
        if (trimmedText.length > 0)
          obcNode.innerText = trimmedText;
        [innerText release];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The leak is `NSString *innerText = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (char *)content];`. I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't access a node's content directly, instead use **xmlNodeGetContent**:

```
        xmlChar *content = xmlNodeGetContent(pnode);
        NSString *innerText = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (char *)content];
        NSString *trimmedText = [innerText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: trimCharSet];
        if (trimmedText.length > 0)
          obcNode.innerText = trimmedText;
        [innerText release];
        // you must free what xmlNodeGetContent returns!
        xmlFree(content);
        break;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your code is leaking, but it seems to me that you have an unsafe assignment of an autoreleased object to obcNode.innerText without retaining it.

Comment: What makes you say that? How do you know whether the `innerText` property is `assign`, `copy` or `retain`?

Comment: obcNode.innerText is a copy property. It should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a guess, but I think your dealloc method for obcnode does not release its innerText instance variable on deallocation.  At first glance, your code fragment looks fine for memory management and that is the only potential error I can see.

The reason why it would be flagging the leak for innerText is possibly that trimmedText uses the same underlying unichar array as innerText but with different start and length values and therefore it retains innerText to stop the unichar array from going away.

Because trimmedText is an immutable string, sending copy to it merely causes it to send retain to itself and return itself, so obcNode owns trimmedText which owns innerText.

Comment: I checked the innerText property, it's released. So if I release my innerText property it should also release trimmedText and then the original innertext.

Comment: I thought that `[innerText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet]` returns an entirely new string. Im thinking that in my case there are 3 different strings in memory the original `xmlChar *content` and then `NSString *innerText` is created and then `NSString *trimmedText`. Both independent from each other. And the only object that should matter to me is innertext because it's not autoreleased. And I think I don't have to release `xmlChar *content` but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: There are three strings but possibly not three underlying unichar arrays.